# React - Overlap css files

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a theme feature in my web-app with two bootstarp css files, one for each theme. I wanna toggle between them but when the end result that they are overlapping.

```
handleThemeToggleClick(dark){
    var new_theme = !this.state.dark_theme
    if(new_theme)
    {
      import("./css/bootstrap-darkly.min.css");
      this.setState({
        dark_theme: new_theme,
      });
    }
    else{
      import("./css/bootstrap-simplex.min.css");
      this.setState({
        dark_theme: new_theme,
      });
    } 
  }
```

Is there a way to un-import a file in react? Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Un-importing the css file wouldn't make a difference. The css styles would've been applied already so they won't just go away unless the user refreshes the browser.

Instead you can re-write all your CSS properties so that your styles don't clash.